# when i wanna update my object, fields with DateField or ImageField are blank, they dont have any data but they are saved in database

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

models.py

```
class Log(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductInfo,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0,verbose_name='کالا')
    number = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False,default=0,verbose_name='تعداد')
   
    date_to_recived = jmodels.jDateTimeField(verbose_name='تاریخ دریافت محصول')
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None,verbose_name='نام و نام خانوادگی فرستنده')
    sender_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None,verbose_name='شماره تلفن فرستنده')
    sender_melli_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None,verbose_name='شماره ملی فرستنده')
    sender_sign = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=image_saving,verbose_name='امضای فرستنده')
    reciver_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None,verbose_name='نام و نام خانوادگی گیرنده')
    reciver_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None,verbose_name='شماره تلفن گیرنده')
    reciver_melli_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None,verbose_name='شماره ملی گیزنده')
    reciver_sign = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=image_saving,verbose_name='امضای گیرنده')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.title} , number of log = {self.id}'
```

serializers.py

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class LogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Log.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = LogSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ['product__title','product__owner__username','reciver_name',
    'sender_name']
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
       
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer_class = LogSerializer(obj)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
 
    def update(self, request, pk):
        obj = Log.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = LogSerializer(obj, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
 
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

i'll be thankfull if you help me.
[image]

this is my imagefield when i wanna update my data.
and my imageFields and datefields are blank.

Comment: Your model has no `DateField` and has 2 `ImageFields`. Which is it? And what exact output are you expecting? If you have errors please also add the full traceback

Comment: please help me :)